# When the discriminant of the quadratic is a root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

A friend of mine gave me this problem

> A quadratic of the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has its discriminant as one of its roots. What is the maximum possible value of $ab$?

I tried Vieta's, Quadratic Formula, even plugging it in, always ending up with complicated expressions that have, as far as I can tell, nothing to do with $ab$.

Is there another method of doing this? Am I missing something obvious? My friend said it shouldn't be too hard.

Thanks!

Comment: @DavidRaveh I think you are wrong. Say $x^2-x=0$ has roots $0$ and $1$, the discriminant is $1$, and $b=-1\ne 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have: $\Delta=\frac{-b-\sqrt {\Delta}}{2a}\,\vee \,\Delta =\frac{-b+\sqrt {\Delta}}{2a}$

Let's write this statement shorter as follows:

$$-b\pm\sqrt {\Delta}=2a\Delta$$

Let $\sqrt {\Delta}=u\ge 0$, then you get

$$
\begin{aligned}&2au^2\pm u+b=0\\ \implies &\Delta_u=1-8ab\ge 0\\
\implies &1\ge 8ab\\
\implies &ab\leq\frac 18.\end{aligned}
$$

---

Explanatory note: Because $u$ is real (assuming $a,b,c$ are real), the discriminant of the quadratic $\Delta_u=1-8ab$ must be non-negative; therefore $\max\{ab\}=\dfrac 18.$

Comment: +1. Note that the full Quadratic Formula expression for $u$ is unnecessary. You can just say that, because $u$ is real (assuming $a$, $b$, $c$ are real), the discriminant of the $u$-quadratic (namely, $1-8ab$) must be non-negative; therefore ...

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Once I used the quadratic formula for the discriminant, all I had to do was take the discriminant again.